# Training on a pre-trained model with new classes

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, image-segmentation

Can I train on the basis of maskrcnn's pre-trained model? If the categories of the pre-trained model are different from those of my own dataset, will the pre-trained model still be effective?

I tried with a new class training dataset. But it seems to converge very slowly.

Comment: I've given a very broad answer to your question. You'll have to provide more details if you want more specific answers. What is your task? What is your dataset? On which dataset was the model pretrained?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, fine-tuning pretrained models on your own dataset is a well established practice. It is common to replace the model's head with your own that will match the number of classes in your dataset and will have randomly initialized weights at first.